# Javascript uncaught type error cannot set property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript

This code is giving an UNCAUGHT TYPE ERROR:CANNOT SET PROPERTY '0' OF UNDEFINED(..)
Why is this giving such error?

```
function node() {
    this.parent = null;
    this.children = [];
}
node.prototype.m = function () {
    var insertchild = function (parent, child) {
        var i;
        if (typeof this.children === "undefined")
            i = 0;
        else
            i = this.children.length;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.children[i] = child;
        console.log(parent + " " + child);
    }
    return insertchild;
}
var n = new node();
n.m()('A', 'B');
```

Comment: Hello Ranojit, what are you trying to achieve with this code?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `this` inside the insertchild function

One solution:

```
function node() {
    this.parent = null;
    this.children = [];
}
node.prototype.m = function() {
    var insertchild = function(parent, child) {
        var i = this.children.length;
        // next four lines are not required
        //if (typeof this.children === "undefined")
        //    i = 0;
        //else
        //    i = this.children.length;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.children[i] = child;
        console.log(parent + " " + child);
    }
    return insertchild.bind(this); // fix is here
}
var n = new node();
n.m()('A', 'B');
```

if you ae in an environment without the .bind() method

```
function node() {
    this.parent = null;
    this.children = [];
}
node.prototype.m = function() {
    var me = this;
    var insertchild = function(parent, child) {
        var i = me.children.length;
        me.parent = parent;
        me.children[i] = child;
        console.log(parent + " " + child);
    }
    return insertchild;
}
var n = new node();
n.m()('A', 'B');
```

I think

Comment: can you tell me what is bind() method and why 'this' is causing a problem in my code?

Comment: bind - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: `this` problem - I know what the problem is, but I'm not good at explaining it

Answer (score 0):

**Within function insertChild(), the `this` keyword refers to the function scope of itself, not the outer scope (instance of node as you want)**

When you are in the scope of the function `insertChild()`, the `this` keyword does not refer to the `node` instance. It is referencing the function scope of insertChild() instead.

**Quick fix**

Since referencing `this` within `insertChild()` function won't refer to `node` instance, you can cope with this easily by just delegating `this` variable with other variable, e.g. `self` so you can still keep a reference with it in `insertChild()` function.

```
node.prototype.m = function () {
    var self = this;
    var insertchild = function (parent, child) {
        var i;
        if (typeof this.children === "undefined")
            i = 0;
        else
            i = self.children.length;
        self.parent = parent;
        self.children[i] = child;
        console.log(parent + " " + child);
    }
    return insertchild;
}
var n = new node();
n.m()('A', 'B');
```